# I can see my YouTube comment's history, but no replies to other comments. Why is that?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

In the comment history of YouTube I can see my comments. However, I do not see my replies **to other comments** in that very list. Why is that?

Furthermore I do not see my replies to other comments in that very YT channel. My comments are visible.

- Is that related to the history issue?
- Can the owner of the YT channel disable just replies and allow comments?
- Or does he has to release the replies?

I have no own YT channel, so I do not know the "other side".

--- Edit 2022-06-17 ----

In [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JstXOp0jjo) he describes a similar problem. It is a Google+ setting of the original poster. While in his description he sees NO reply button, I see one, but my REPLY is swallowed.

Some similar cases on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Why-isnt-YouTube-showing-my-replies-to-comments

---

Edit 2022-06-22: Remains a mystery. Same channel, other comment, and I was able to reply. But after I wanted to edit my reply another time, I saw a little info "error occurred" info below and the edits got lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its relatively straightforward to find you comment history in both the mobile YT app and on PC.

**Mobile**

[image]

**PC**

Select the hamburger menu (three parallel line icon) to the left of the YT screen and from there select `History`.

[image]

Select the `History` option and you will be presented with a screen listing your YT comments.

[image]

Then select `Comments` from the menu that appears on the right of your screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case it shows my direct 1st level comments to a video. But it does NOT show the responses I have given to comments of other people with "REPLY".

I have replied to a comment and I do not see this at all. First I thought I have made a mistake, but when I save a REPLY to a comment it is not visible.

I neither see this reply in my history nor under the comment. So i was wondering if the channel owner has to release those. Other people have responded at 2nd level (REPLY to COMMENT) and it is visbible.

Comment: I'm not aware of that... I just checked my own history and comments screens and it is fully up to date.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful as it appears it has something to do with that channel. Will have an eye on it. In the first reply I have used an URL, so I thought it is because of that (and some fraud protection). But the 2nd reply was without any links.

Comment: if my answer addresses your question, please consider accepting it which may help others with a similar related question. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I always close my questions. I only wait some more days to see if anybody has the exact answer, otherwise I will close with the most suitable answer (in this moment yours). Thanks for your input.